# Nginx rewrite redirects using proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Is it possible to access an address and upload its content without having to redirect to the original site?

What I'm trying to do, I want my users inside my internal network that access the internal site `mysite.digital` be presented with the content of the external site ( hosted on Cloudflare) `https://siteseguro.com`

*I can also remove from Cloudflare if necessary*

I got it with the configuration below, but when accessing the site it redirects me to the original URL. *I need to hide the DNS/IP of the real website.*

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location ^~ / {
        proxy_pass https://brasilia.com;
        proxy_set_header Host brasilia.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate problems

### Redirect

Redirects are caused by two headers `Location` and `Refresh`. Nginx offers you [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) that will handle that for you:

```
proxy_redirect https://brasilia.com http://mysite.digital;
```

### Links

The website may contain relative links `/link` or `link`, in which case you are ok with the first solution. In case there are complete links to the original URL (`https://brasilia.com/link` or `//brasilia.com/link`) you will need to rewrite also the response body. Rewriting the body is something [described here](https://superuser.com/questions/690916/how-to-make-nginx-rewrite-uris-in-http-body-content).